# sql query escape strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
declare @ID VARCHAR(50)='XXXXX'
declare @period int= 1
declare @fromDate DATETIME= '2022-01-23 12:52:42.520'
declare @periodEnd DATETIME= '2023-01-23 12:52:42.520'
EXEC('select count(*) as count from pagesas with (nolock) where domainId=''' + @ID+ ''' and paid=1 and
    source = 2 and clickedOn BETWEEN'''+@fromDate+'AND'''+@periodEnd+'''')
```

I get an error of incorrect syntax

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near 'Jan'.
> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string

Comment: Which DBMS? What error message are you getting?

Comment: TSQL
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'Jan'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.

Comment: SQL Server? `+ @fromDate + ''' AND` instead of`+@fromDate+'AND`?

Comment: Why are you using `EXEC({literal string})` syntax at all here? There's nothing dynamic about your SQL.

Comment: Definitely get rid of the `nolock` hints. It's not an automatic "go faster" trick (don't you think if it were, it would be included by default by now?). And in fact, any case where it does actually help is because the locks it's ignoring were actually important, and it's also a case where you are very like to use stale data.

Answer (score 2):

There is *literally* no need for your `EXEC ({Literal String})` syntax here. Also, that query would *not* generate the error you state; you would get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is because you are trying to concatenate a `datetime` to a `varchar`, but as a `varchar` has a *lower* data type precedence this actually means you are trying to add (as in addition) the `varchar` values to a `datetime` and thus those strings need to be converted to a `datetime` too.

Just use a properly parametrise query; there is literally no need for your "dynamic" SQL here:

```sql
DECLARE @ID varchar(50) = 'XXXXX',
        @period int = 1,
        @fromDate datetime = '2022-01-23T12:52:42.520',
        @periodEnd datetime = '2023-01-23T12:52:42.520';

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM dbo.pagesas --WITH (NOLOCK) --I very much doubt you know what this means, so I suggest you don't use it.
WHERE domainId = @ID
  AND paid = 1
  AND source = 2
  AND clickedOn BETWEEN @fromDate AND @periodEnd;
```

*[Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)*

Comment: He gets the error in the question because there's not a `'` included in the string literal following `@fromDate`, so the `AND whatever` is still part of the first date. Then, when the second date is include (which is a date in January), the syntax is wrong.

Comment: Apart from that would happen *if* the statement could be executed, @JoelCoehoorn . It can't be, as the concatentation would fail before the executed even began.

Comment: But yes, the rest of this is right. No need for `EXEC()`. And if he **did** need it, it should use `sp_executesql()`

Comment: To add to @JoelCoehoorn 's comment, just changing to `sys.sp_executesql` isn't enough if you continue to inject the parameters. As "stupid" as it sounds, you need to **parametrise** the parameters;  `sys.sp_executesql` doesn't offer additional protection from SQL injection when you have a poorly written (dynamic) statement, but it does *enable* you to actually **parametrise** the statement. You would still need to sanitise and properly quote anything that can't be parametrised (such as object names).